# How to use PNPM with Google Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build, pnpm

I'd like to migrate to PNPM, however, I can't find a way to use its lockfile on Google Cloud. My current `cloudbuild` config is the following:

```yaml
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest"
  entrypoint: 'gcloud'
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

Afaik these official images only support Yarn and NPM. Is there an easy way to replace Yarn with PNPM here?

I looked on the [Cloud Builders GitHub repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders), but there's no PNPM there either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC the App Engine standard Node runtime(s) require that you use npm or yarn. PNPM is thus **not** user-definable when using standard.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/specifying-dependencies

If you want to use App Engine with a different package manager you could use flex and define a custom runtime. This essentially allows you to define a container image to deploy to App Engine and this may be anything that exposes an httpd on `:8080`.

Comment: This answer is outdated, `pnpm` is now supported

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `pnpm install` followed by `npm shrinkwrap`. I think `gcloud deploy` will ignore what's in `node_modules` in favor of `package-lock.json` but you could delete it.

```bash
npm i -g pnpm && pnpm i && npm shrinkwrap
```

That's `npm shrinkwrap`. There is `pnpm shrinkwrap` but that generates a pnpm-style lockfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash:

```yaml
- id: Install pnpm
  name: 'node:20'
  script: |
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    npm install --global pnpm@8.5.1
    pnpm install
    pnpm test
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using bash as entrypoint with args

```yaml
  - name: 'node:latest'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: 
      - '-c'
      - |
        npm install -g pnpm &&
        pnpm install &&
        pnpm run build
```